# Why str.charAt(i) is 1.6 times faster than str[i] in Node.js

Tags: javascript, string, node.js

```
var s = '', ok = ' h dfb  ds84 78sgf  ydf hjb////**', lc = 0, cc = 0

for (var i = 0; i < 300000; i++) {
    s += ok[Math.floor(Math.random() * ok.length)]
}

console.time('[]')
for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    if (s[i] == '/' && s[i+1] == '/') lc++, i++
    if (s[i] == '/' && s[i+1] == '*') cc++, i++
}
console.timeEnd('[]')
/*
console.time('charAt')
for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    if (s.charAt(i) == '/' && s.charAt(i+1) == '/') lc++, i++
    if (s.charAt(i) == '/' && s.charAt(i+1) == '*') cc++, i++
}
console.timeEnd('charAt')
*/
console.time('regex')
var rlc = (s.match(/\/\//g) || []).length;
var rcc = (s.match(/\/\*/g) || []).length;
console.timeEnd('regex')

console.log(lc, cc, rlc==lc, rcc==cc)
```

Why str.charAt() is consistently showing about 1.6 performance improvement over str[]? Aren't they supposed to do the same thing the same way? Does [] do some extra checks or conversions that affect speed? Or is it rather about my code?

Furthermore why `str.charCodeAt(i) == 42` is another 10% faster than `str.charAt(i) == '/'`? From C/C++ point of view it makes no sense at all.

UPDATE: I put whole test code here.

UPDATE2: I must say that this is observed using Node.js ver 0.11.4

http://jsperf.com/brackets-vs-charat3
This test case shows lesser difference. charAt() is slower 6% in chrome 37 and 1% faster in Firefox 33. All Ubuntu 64.

UPDATE 3, since this seems to be Node.js issue I add node.js tag

Comment: Do you have a JSPerf for this?

Comment: Did you test it yourself or do you have another source? Also, what is the length of `s`? A short `s` will certainly effect your measurements.

Comment: I updated the code to show complete test app

Comment: Odd, i would have expected the opposite.

Comment: added http://jsperf.com/brackets-vs-charat3

Comment: I would guess that `s[i]` is actually doing something not truly Array under the covers. Oh, wait a minute, now I remember, let me look at up, it is something like that!

Comment: how does JSPERF helps? it's for browsers..Node is not a browser..i'm not sure the results will qualify

Comment: @vsync, in my original post I did not say it's node, who would expect their v8 is so different from chrome?

Comment: BTW, pretty cool. How did you stumble across this?

Comment: it is known that IE8 and below don't support array index pointers like `arr[i]`, so for years developers were using `charAt`. now there is a new wave of developers who doesn't know this, but originally browsers were opt to `chatAt`

Answer (score 4):

> Aren't they supposed to do the same thing the same way?

No. Apart from obviously different ways, they don't do the same things. Check the [spec for  `charAt`](http://es5.github.io/#x15.5.4.4) and [for `[]` on strings](http://es5.github.io/#x15.5.5.2).

> Does [] do some extra checks or conversions that affect speed?

Apparently. The differences are that `charAt` needs to cast its operand to a string, which `[]` doesn't need to do. Furthermore, `charAt` will return the empty string for out-of-bounds accesses, while `[]` will return undefined. And mostly, `[]` needs to check whether the given property name is really an integer, and whether there is an *actual property* with that name on the string object.

> Or is it rather about my code?

Your code looks fine.

> Furthermore why str.charCodeAt(i) == 42 is another 10% faster than str.charAt(i) == '/'? From C/C++ point of view it makes no sense at all.

Notice that JavaScript does not have a `char` datatype. `'/'` is a *string* of length 1. It seems this is not optimized well (or: easily), and an integer<sup>1</sup> comparison is just faster than a string comparison.

<sub>1: Most numbers, though "per spec" being 64-bit floats, are represented as 31-bit integers in V8.</sub>

Comment: If "charAt needs to cast its operand to a string" (extra operation) and "charAt will return the empty string" (instead of just `undefined`, extra operation) - why charAt is FASTER?

Comment: Actually, casting to string can be optimised away pretty easily (and it is done for method calls on primitive values in most engines automatically). Also I'd assume that the emtpy string makes less operations than `undefined` - and as a bonus, you get type safety and can avoid type checks in the comparison. Regardless, I listed those things only to exhibit the differences between the operations, not to say that one is faster than the other. I'd guess the property lookup in `[]` is optimised away on primitive values similarly.

Comment: [Tests](http://jsperf.com/brackets-vs-charat3/2) seem to suggest that all these optimisations are done anyway, and both methods are similarly fast on primitive strings. Not so much on string objects…

Answer (score -2):

Quote from Crockford's "JavaScript: the Good Parts", opening paragraphs of Chap 6, Arrays:

> ... Arrays can be very fast data structures. Unfortunately, JavaScript does not have anything like this kind of array.
>   Instead, JavaScript provides an object that has some array-like characteristics. It converts array subscripts into strings that are used to make properties. It is significantly slower than a real array...

So whereas in C or Java arr[2] is a direct pointer to a memory location and thus should have very fast performance, in JS, arr[2] really means, "convert the number 2 into the string '2', then hash it to use as a lookup in an object."

Hashed lookups are still pretty fast, but not as fast as true arrays. Add to it that the number needs to be converted to a string and then hashed, and you see the performance hit.

On the other hand, `str.charAt(2)` is, I believe, a native function and is probably doing true array-like lookup under the covers.

Comment: Now, this answer is on subject and correct AFAIK. So why in the world did someone vote it down without at least commenting what issue they have with it?

Comment: "JS: The good parts" seems to be quite outdated on that topic. Every modern engine does use actual arrays for `Array` objects under the hood today. Also, this question is not about objects or arrays, *it's about strings!*

Comment: I cannot recall offhand, but I think that the underlying `str[i]` used the same mechanism. I could be off. Either way a- would like to see a good explanation, b- they use actual arrays? I haven't delved into the source code recently.